# Iptable input icmp on interface

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm trying to accept all incoming `icmp` traffic from a `192.168.1.0/24` on the interface `eth0`.

Here is my command

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

This command is on a file. So when i execute the file `/etc/file` i get this error:

```
Bad argument 'icmp'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two points:

- The `-p` (`--protocol`) option name before `icmp`
- `--icmp-type 8` is Echo_Request (type 8), not Echo_Response (type 0), you need `--icmp type 0`

Do:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Worked, thank you. I accepted your comment as the solution.